# Populate the field if it is empty using Apex/Trigger

Tags: trigger

Problem: How to check if a field is empty? If it is empty, auto-populate a custom field.
Example Scenario:

**Case Object**
Picklist 1 - has its own value &
Picklist 2 - dependent to picklist 1

**Task Object**
Picklist 3 - has its own value also
(Note: Picklist 1 & Picklist 2 will be concatenate here at Picklist 3)

1. If I add a new task then I did not choose a value from a picklist 3, the picklist 1 & picklist 2 will populate the picklist 3(concatenated).
2. If I add a new task and choose a value from picklist 3 then the value that I choose in picklist 3 will be saved and disregard the auto-populate from Picklist 1 & 2.

Below is my code for auto-populate.
I am using a before insert trigger.

```
 public void autoPopulate(List<SObject> newList){
    
    List<Task> newListTask = (List<Task>) newList;
    Set <Id> setCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
    Map<Id, String> mapCaseCateg = new Map<Id, String>();
    
    for(Task t: newListTask){
        setCaseIds.add(t.WhatId);
    }
    
    
    if(!setCaseIds.isEmpty()){
        for(Case c: [Select Id, Category__c, Subcategory__c FROM Case Where Id =:setCaseIds]){
            mapCaseCateg.put(c.Id, c.Category__c +' - '+c.Subcategory__c);
           
        }
                    
    }
    
    
     if(!mapCaseCateg.isEmpty()){
       for(Task t: newListTask){
      t.Task_Category__c = mapCaseCateg.get(t.WhatId);
     }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Your code is not checking for a null field anywhere.  Please [edit] your post to include that code, and also clarify your details to explain the specific field names  you are working with, instead of the generic Picklist1 etc which is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite this to be a bit more concise with clearer variable names. I'm assuming that `newList` represents `Trigger.new`

```
public void autoPopulate(Task[] tasks) {
  Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
   // Step 1 - Get CaseIds from Task's WhatId; ignore tasks without WhatId or non-Case WhatIds
  for (Task t : tasks) {
       if (isAutoPopulateableTask(t)) {caseIds.add(t.WhatId);}
  }
  // Step 2 Build map of Cases by CaseId 
  Map<Id,Case> casesById = new Map<Id,Case>();
  if (!caseIds.isEmpty()) {
    casesById = new Map<Id,Case> ( [SELECT Id, Category__c, SubCategory__c 
                FROM Case WHERE Id IN: caseIds]);
  
  // Step 3 - Coerce the Task's category from its related Case unless entered by user
  for (Task t: tasks) {
    if (isAutoPopulateableTask(t)) {
      t.Task_Category__c = String.isNotBlank(t.Task_Category__c)
           ? t.Task_Category__c  // leave as entered by user
           : casesById.get(t.WhatId).Category__c + ' - ' +
             casesById.get(t.WhatId).SubCategory__c;
      }
   }
}

private Boolean isAutoPopulateableTask(Task t) {
   return t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Case.SobjectType;
}
```

Comment: Why is it having an error in isAutoPopulateableTask and Boolean?

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isAutoPopulateableTask(Task) from the type handler

Comment: Variable does not exist: Boolean

Comment: both methods need to be in the same class